# Virtual field does not appear in REST JSON result

Tags: rest, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a `Model` named **Users** with a virtual field named full_name, and it works fine in the template by calling:

```
<?= $user->full_name; ?>
```

But it doesn't automatically come to the REST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the docs:

> By default virtual properties are not exported when converting
>   entities to arrays or JSON. In order to expose virtual properties you
>   need to make them visible. When defining your entity class you can
>   provide a list of virtual properties that should be exposed:
>
> ```
> namespace App\Model\Entity;
>
> use Cake\ORM\Entity;
>
> class User extends Entity
> {
>
>     protected $_virtual = ['full_name'];
>
> }
> ```
>
> This list can be modified at runtime using `virtualProperties`:
>
> ```
> $user->virtualProperties(['full_name', 'is_admin']);
> ```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Exposing Virtual Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields)**

Comment: **Note**: for CakePHP5 specify **array**, i.e. `protected array $_virtual`, otherwise *Fatal error: Type of $_virtual must be array (as in class Cake\ORM\Entity)*